# Draw 3D objects over 2D images in Python

Tags: python, image, 3d

There are many ways to draw objects over 2d images. There are also many ways to draw 3D objects, as graphs over plots.

However, I did not find a way to draw 3D objects over 2D images. For example, let's say I want to draw a black cube over a picture:

[image]

Is there any Python package that enables this?

Answer (score 0):

Never saw this in matplotlib to be honest. So here a littl workaround:
write 2 independent scripts, one for the plain background and one for the 3D object. Then you could merge them via Gimp, photoshop etc.

```
#for the background
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
plt.axis('off')
image = mpimg.imread("C:\path\to\image\xyz.jpg")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What script is needed for the background? It is just a plain image... Anyway I need a programmatic solution, doesn't have to be in Python but it can't be manual with Photoshop

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? Instead of seeing the background image I am seeing a constant color image, with the most dominant color in the image...

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import matplotlib.image as mpimg;
plt.axis('off');
image = mpimg.imread("C:\....\....\figure.jpg"); #(windows)
plt.imshow(image);
plt.show()

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, after I generated the 3D object